# where are the items in a document library?

Tags: document-library, email

Just inherited this issue that was left from previous developer so i have NO knowledge of how the process is working. Actually, user sends email to an email account and then the document gets pushed into a document library. How did he (the developer) configured this so I can find out why is not pushing data into the document library anymore?

Edited: I found some link and I think it's a good start but I would still be interested to learn why the email is not pushing to the library anymore.

http://sharepointgeorge.com/2010/configuring-incoming-email-sharepoint-2010/
http://www.sharepointedutech.com/2010/10/27/how-to-setup-mail-enabled-document-libraries-in-sharepoint-2010-part-4/

Edited:

Actually, everything was configured properly. I think I had to go into central admin and re-submit my "incomming mail config" (without even changing anything on this screen). That did it. I guess it reforces the timer job to start this process. After this step, I went to Document library and made sure everything is configured propertly (everything was find and made no change) and I click OK (instead of cancel, even though everything looked good).

Now it's working. I guess some magic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incoming email is first delivered to the dropbox of an SMTP server, then picked up by SharePoint using a timer job to route to a properly configured document library. Troubleshooting steps:

- is a .EML file being delivered to the SMTP server dropbox
- is SharePoint incoming email settings configured to correctly  to pick it up
- is the timer job service running and is the timer job executing
- is the document library properly configured with the correct incoming email address

Answer (score 1):

Check Central Admin configuration, and ensure you have an emailed enabled list, and record those settings.

Check your drop folder?  Is there email there, this at least lets you know it's being delivered, but SharePoint is not picking it up.  If there is no mail, then SP may be picking it up or may not, you can check by dropping a TXT file formatted as mail in the folder, but I prefer to do a SMTP check to ensure SMTP is working correctly.

---

**SMTP Check**

Ensure the SMTP service is installed and enabled on the server(s) that is receiving email.  If it is a load balanced configuration, you may wan to consider disabling SMTP on all but a single server.

Verify the properties of the SMTP service.  Should be enabled for Anonymous.  If it is restricting relays by IP, ensure your client IP is added so we can test it (you should be restricting by IP since Anon. needs to be enabled).

I recommend having the server open in a remote session, and open your configured drop folder so you can watch incoming mail.

On your client, open and perform the following:

Telnet yourservername 25

helo

mail from: your email address

rcpt to: list mail address

data

subject: any subject here

body here

.

Note you need to hit enter after each line, you should get a 250 response back, saying everything was ok.  the last line you need to type "." and hit enter, this ques the message for delivery.  You should see it appear in your drop box.

---

If it stays in the drop box SP is not picking it up.  If it disappears within about 5 minutes (depends on how often you are checking the drop folder) SP is picking it up.

If you don't see anything something is wrong with your SMTP settings.

If SP did pick it up but its not in the library, it is a permission issue.  The FROM address must be associated with a person that has rights to the library.

If SP didn't pick it up, ensure the TO address is configured for an email enabled library.  This is done in the library settings under "incoming email settings".

If all this is good, and you are using exchange, you need to verify that exchange is configured to forward email to your server.

Answer (score 0):

I would rule out the obvious and see if the library is still set for incoming email.  There should be an option to check this on the settings for that particular library.